# Topic replication in Apache Pulsar

Tags: apache-pulsar

The documentation on [replication in Pulsar](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/latest/getting-started/ConceptsAndArchitecture/#Replication) is not very descriptive.
I am wondering how the replication works in detail and how the [persistence policies for a namespace](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/latest/reference/CliTools/#pulsar-admin-namespaces-set-persistence) play into this. The documentation talks about these parameters

- `bookkeeper-ack-quorom`: The number of acks (guaranteed copies) to wait for each entry
- `bookkeeper-ensemble`: The number of bookies to use for a topic
- `bookkeeper-write-quorum`: How many writes to make of each entry

Does `bookkeeper-ack-quorom` mean, that the ack to the client is delayed until this number of bookies have written the entry to disk?

What is the difference between `bookkeeper-ensemble` and `bookkeeper-write-quorum`?

Lets assume I have 3 bookies and I want topics in the namespace to reside on each of them, then I set both values to `3`?

Comment: It seems that the anchor of the urls is changed on every reload, therefore the links do not link to the direct section. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does bookkeeper-ack-quorom mean, that the ack to the client is delayed until this number of bookies have written the entry to disk?

That's correct. If your ack-quorum is 2 it means you will have 2 guaranteed copies of the message when the publish is successful.
In the default configuration, that will mean that the message is written to disk and flushed (fsynced) to disk on 2 machines.

> What is the difference between bookkeeper-ensemble and bookkeeper-write-quorum?

Ensemble is the number of bookies to be used for a ledger. Most of the time this is configured to be equal than write quorum.

Setting `ensemble > write-quorum` will enable "striping of entries across multiple bookies within a single topic.

For example, setting `e=5` `w=2` `a=2` will make:

- Each message is written in 2 copies and we wait for 2 acks
- Messages are striped in round-robin across 5 bookies
- Each bookie will have a subset of the messages 2/5
- Each bookie will have a small write/read traffic

Basically it allows to scale up the IO for a single ledger without relaxing ordering.

> Lets assume I have 3 bookies and I want topics in the namespace to reside on each of them, then I set both values to 3?

Correct. Although `ensemble` also represent the minimum set of bookies that need to be available in order for writes to be accepted.

If you have 3 bookies and set `ensemble=3`, you won't be able to tolerate a node failure.

Comment: Regarding your last statement, as the `ensemble > write-quorum` case is just a (greatly appreciated!) measure for greater performance, wouldn't it in theory be possible for Pulsar to still allow writing as long as the number of nodes is at least equal to the write-quorum? Then we could have the best mix of availability and performance.

Comment: Actually, the current behavior is to require at least "ensemble" nodes to up, though it could be improved to only require "write-quorum" nodes.